# Applying the central limit theorem

Tags: probability-theory

I have a sequence of $n$ independent Bernoulli random variables where I only know that parameter $p_i$ is in $[1/2 - 1/n,1/2 + 1/n]$. Is it still possible to apply the central limit theorem to say that the sum of these random variables are normally distributed, as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

I was looking at Lindeberg's condition on wikipedia, is this the right tool?

**Edit:** the answer below addresses the case where $p_i \in [1/2 - 1/i,1/2 + 1/i]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lindeberg's theorem yields readily the conclusion. If the random variables $X_k$ are Bernoulli $\pm1$ with parameter $p_k$ with the condition on $(p_k)$ you indicate , then the normalizing factor $\mathrm{var}(X_1+\cdots+X_n)$ is $n+O(1)$ hence one can divide by $\sqrt{n}$ just like in the usual case and the centering term $\mathbb E(X_1+\cdots+X_n)=O(\log n)$ is $o(\sqrt{n})$ hence it can be omitted.

More generally, $p_k=\frac12(1+r_k)$ would do, as long as $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n|r_k|\to0$.

Comment: [Lindeberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition), not Lindenberg.

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand your answer correctly, the central limit theorem won't be applicable if $p_i \in [1/2 - 1/\sqrt{n},1/2 + 1/\sqrt{n}]$ right?

Comment: The variance $n+o(n)$ will still be all right but the mean shall be $O(\sqrt{n})$ hence it will not disappear due to the normalizing factor. Thus $(S_n-E(S_n))/\sqrt{n}$ will be approximately normal, but not always $S_n/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: One more thing, how did you get an expected value of $O(\log n)$ in your answer? Since each $X_i$ is a Bernoulli trial, isn't $\mathbb{E}(X_i) \leq (1/2 + 1/n) - (1/2-1/n) = 2/n$ and thus $\mathbb{E}(X_1+\cdots+X_n) \leq 2$?

Comment: I just realized I misread the condition on $(p_k)$... My answer addresses the case $p_k\in[1/2-1/k,1/2+1/k]$ but you wrote $p_k\in[1/2-1/n,1/2-1/n]$. Sorry about the confusion. But I must say I do not understand the condition, now: assuming that $p_{42}\in[1/2-1/n,1/2+1/n]$ and considering the limit $n\to\infty$ yields $p_{42}=1/2$, no? Or, at the $n$th stage, does one choose anew $n+1$ random variables $(X_k^{(n+1)})_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n+1}$, with new parameters $(p_k^{(n+1)})_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n+1}$ such that $p_k^{(n+1)}\in[1/2-1/n,1/2+1/n]$? Please clarify.

Comment: It is the former case, the range of the probability $\rightarrow 1/2$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. But for applying the classic CLT, the RVs need to be i.i.d for *every* $n$, not just in the limit, right?

Comment: Hence you do consider a triangular array of random variables $(X_k^{(n)})_{n\geqslant1,1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ such that the distribution of $X^{(n)}_k$ depends on $n$ and the random variables $(X_k^{(n)})_k$ are i.i.d., right? Then [this](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/pitman/s205f02/lecture10.pdf) applies, no? Note that the $(n,k)$ entry $X_k^{(n)}$ of the array would be a Bernoulli divided by $\sqrt{4np_k^{(n)}(1-p_k^{(n)})}\sim\sqrt{n}\to\infty$ hence Lindeberg's sum would be trivially zero for every large enough $n$.

Comment: The LATTER case, no?

Comment: yes, the latter.